# Print columns side by side in python

Tags: python, printing, line

When applying this code: (for example)

```py
x = ["Apple\napple", "Orange\norange", "Banana\nbanana"]
for i in x:
    print(i, end = " ")
```

The result is:

```
Apple
apple Orange
orange Banana
banana
```

But I need a way to make it like this:

```
Apple Orange Banana
apple orange banana
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide more information on your question. You will get more responses that way. Edit your question and place the code using code block for better visibility. You can also add more code to your question so that we can understand the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to split element of x to y first
- Then print indiced index of element in y

Try this code below

```
x = ["Apple\napple", "Orange\norange", "Banana\nbanana"]
y = [x[i].split() for i in range(len(x))]
print(f'{y[0][0]} {y[1][0]} {y[2][0]}\n{y[0][1]} {y[1][1]} {y[2][1]}')
```